# Permission to use image

Tags: discussion

I would like to request permission to use an image posted on this site.  The image is of twining vines which would be used in section transition pages, to suggest twining of content between chapters, in a book entitled "Spatial Thinking in Environmental Contexts:  Maps, Archives, and Timelines" to be published in 2019 by CRC Press (a division of Taylor & Francis).  The url for the image, as found on your site, is:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKZba.jpg  Please advise with granting of permission and desired form for citation.  Thank you.  Sandra L. Arlinghaus, Ph.D., Editor, Spatial Thinking in Enviromental Contexts.

Answer (score 7):

From a [reverse Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=intertwined%20vines&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSlgEJcFQBhQVguG0aigELEKjU2AQaBAgUCAMMCxCwjKcIGmEKXwgDEielBvgB0QueEu0KWtsO7AqhBLgZ4CzBIIokqTjaKac4liSZJKg48zcaMF8ifTLTavH3c0nn8lYi7cMzwe1rru79Hl9dopyxRfC_1obBl-TclHgDlulvEzeQ-iCAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIENB_1EuQw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRlNecge7eAhVwhOAKHReyD5cQ2A4IKigB), it seems that the photograph is owned by Ian Sauer of the blog website [Carolina Wandering 2](https://carolinawandering2.com/tag/intertwine/). I would try contacting him directly. (You can refer to the comments below the [About page](https://carolinawandering2.com/about/).)

To be clear, it doesn't appear as if Stack Exchange or anybody who posted to Stack Exchange holds ownership of the image.

Comment: The asker who used the image should have referenced the source in the question. I've now done that.